# new Popup window url is not loading javascript in the script tag of the page

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery, popup

I have a jsp page with some grids. each row is a dynamically loaded .jsp page coming from server-side.
on selecting a row i want the page to be displayed in pop-up window.

It loads my jsp well but there is a  tag in the head section having all the javascript functions to be called on different element of page.

In my console script panel is showing no source found. Hence my javascript is not loading.

This is how i am calling my new page..

```
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: url, data:form, success: function(response) {
    var win = window.open('','_blank','toolbar=yes, menubar=yes, location=no, fullscreen=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=1600, height=600');
   if(win == null || typeof(win) == "undefined") {
        alert("Please enable popups in your browser settings to continue.");  
   }
   with(win.document)
   {
      open();
      write(response);
      close();
   }                    
   $(win).unload(function() {
   $("#ResultSet").flexReload();
 });
```

Comment: the `no source found` is on parent or child window? Can you please provide a sample html either here or on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: on child window. My jsp page from server side is loading fine in the child window. but javascript is not working on child window.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with this issue and i happen to solve it.
So this is what i did, if any newbie like me gets stuck..

Issue was happening cause My child window was trying to run JavaScript before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded.

and jquery was not getting loaded from the parent file.

plus sequence of the files that were included was wrong.

jquery has to be first in the sequence then your js files.